# Unexpected output of xsd.exe

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

Consider the following simple schema:

[image: XSD schema]

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="MyRoot">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:group ref="MyChoice" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:group name="MyChoice">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="c" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>
</xs:schema>
```

When turning this into C# code with xsd.exe (VS2017), I get the following output:

```
public partial class MyRoot {

    private string[] aField;

    private string[] bField;

    private string[] cField;

    // ... omitted for brevity ...
}
```

This code has a major problem: in the XSD/XML all of the sub-elements (a, b and c) were **ordered**.
This order is now **lost** in the C# class, since there are three different arrays for each of the sub elements.

Is xsd.exe doing it wrong? Or am I using it wrong? Or is the .xsd file flawed?

Comment: When the `<choice>` appears directly in the `<sequence>` it seems to do something more sensible (one array of values, one array indicating which element type to use for each item in the first array). Do you need this named `<group>`?

Comment: Sadly the .xsd file is given and cannot be changed. I have to work with what I got ;-)